# How to create and upload data to json file in s3?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, .net-core

Hi I am writing Lambda function in .Net core. My requirement is Post api will send employee data. When data is received I want to store it in S3 bucket. The approach I am following is whenever Api sends data to lambda, Empid is unique. Each time I want to create one json file and name of the file should be equal to emp id. I am trying to write my function as below.

```
public async Task<string> FunctionHandler(Employee input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            string bucketname = "someunquebucket";
            var client = new AmazonS3Client();
            bool doesBucketExists = await AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExistV2Async(client,bucketname);
            if(!doesBucketExists)
            {
                var request = new PutBucketRequest
                {
                    BucketName = "someunquebucket",
                };
            var response = await client.PutBucketAsync(request);
            }
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bin))
            {
                var request = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketname,
                    InputStream = stream,
                    ContentType = "application/json",
                    Key = input.emp_id
                };
            var response = await client.PutObjectAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
```

In the above code, PutObjectRequest is used to write data to s3 bucket. I am adding few parameters like bucketname etc. In the function I am receiving Employee data. Now I want to create json file with emp id. I found above code but I am not sure what to pass in place of bin. Can someone help me to execute the above function. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I would convert json to Base 64 string and send the string : Convert.ToBase64String("string");

Answer (score 2):

I am new to .Net Core, and came across your post while trying to solve a similar problem.

Here is how I was able to upload a json response string to my s3 Bucket (Hope it helps)

```
String timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonString);
var seekableStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
seekableStream.Position = 0;
var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = this.BucketName,
    Key = timeStamp+"_"+reg + ".json",
    InputStream = seekableStream
};
try
{
var response2 = await this.S3Client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);}
```

Hope you sorted your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is the example code from AWS SDK Code Examples.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/dotnetv3/S3

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/dotnetv3/S3/S3_Basics/S3Bucket.cs#L45

```
/// <summary>
/// Shows how to upload a file from the local computer to an Amazon S3
/// bucket.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="client">An initialized Amazon S3 client object.</param>
/// <param name="bucketName">The Amazon S3 bucket to which the object
/// will be uploaded.</param>
/// <param name="objectName">The object to upload.</param>
/// <param name="filePath">The path, including file name, of the object
/// on the local computer to upload.</param>
/// <returns>A boolean value indicating the success or failure of the
/// upload procedure.</returns>
public static async Task<bool> UploadFileAsync(
    IAmazonS3 client,
    string bucketName,
    string objectName,
    string filePath)
{
    var request = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = objectName,
        FilePath = filePath,
    };

    var response = await client.PutObjectAsync(request);
    if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Successfully uploaded {objectName} to {bucketName}.");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Could not upload {objectName} to {bucketName}.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is a modified service I wrote to upload json strings as json files both with sync and async methods:

```
public class AwsS3Service
{
    private readonly IAmazonS3 _client;
    private readonly string _bucketName;
    private readonly string _keyPrefix;

    /// <param name="bucketName">The Amazon S3 bucket to which the object
    /// will be uploaded.</param>
    public AwsS3Service(string accessKey, string secretKey, string bucketName, string keyPrefix)
    {
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        _client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        _bucketName=bucketName;
        _keyPrefix=keyPrefix;
    }
    
    public bool UploadJson(string objectName, string json, int migrationId, long orgId)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => UploadJsonAsync(objectName, json, migrationId, orgId)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    
    public async Task<bool> UploadJsonAsync(string objectName, string json, int migrationId, long orgId)
    {
        var request = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = $"{_bucketName}",
            Key = $"{_keyPrefix}{migrationId}/{orgId}/{objectName}",
            InputStream =  new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)),
        };

        var response = await _client.PutObjectAsync(request);
        if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```